# Does Process.Responding work with hidden GUI processes?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, process

I have a service that creates a child process that runs in the background. The child process is actually a GUI application, but generally runs hidden in the background. With the GUI hidden in this manner will Process.Responding still work correctly?

Comment: Have you tried it? that's probably an easy way for you to find out..........

Comment: I just don't have a good way to test the "not responding" part. I suppose I could put the process in an infinite loop to make it unresponsive.

Comment: It does seem to work. At least it returns true even if the window is hidden.